# Curl Ubuntu Post Request Doesn't receive file

Tags: linux, post, ubuntu, curl, request

So I'm trying to download ventrilo from their website

```
http://www.ventrilo.com/dlprod.php?id=102
```

As far as I'm aware what I'm showing is identical to the request that the page makes when you click accept, does anyone know why this isn't working?

```
curl -o ventrilo.tar.gz "http://dlx2.ventrilo.com/dl.php?server_linux_i386&8882453279444" -H 
"Origin: http://www.ventrilo.com" 
-H "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch" 
-H "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8" 
-H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36(KHTML, like     Gecko)     Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36" 
-H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" 
-H "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8" 
-H "Cache-Control: max-age=0" -H "Referer: http://www.ventrilo.com/dlprod.php?id=102"
-H "Connection: keep-alive" --data "Download=I+Agree" --compressed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice this bold number from your POST url server_linux_i386&**8882453279444**. Using the number they are tracking the session.

There are two things can happen:

1) May be you have collected the url from the page's source and tried after a long time when the session is expired.

2) May be you collected the url from your pc and tried to execute at your server(or vice-versa).

Comment: This seems to be exactly the problem, thanks for the insight, is there a easy way to start a session in ubuntu server or a tool I could use to view it during a request?

Comment: To be specific the session seems to last a long time but it was the session of my pc that I was using

Comment: Download the page on your ubuntu using `curl` or `wget`. From the html page you can easily catch the `number` by viewing the source using `less`, `vi`, etc commands. Also you can use `grep` to get the number as well.